# How can my TimeSeries Plot starts at "00:00" and finish at "23:00" ? Without spaces on the sides

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

**I need to plot without those spaces on the sides (left and right)**

As I am a new user in Stack Overflow, I can't show an image here, the link is: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5NvR.png)

This is my code:

```
by_time_month = []
for i in range(12):
    b_t_m = demand[f'2019-{i+1}'].groupby(demand[f'2019-{i+1}'].index.time).mean()
    by_time_month.append(b_t_m)
    i=i+1

hourly_ticks_3 = 3*60*60*np.arange(8)

months = ('Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=2, figsize=(13, 22))

for by_month, ax, subtitle in zip(by_time_month, fig.get_axes(), months):
    ax.plot(by_month, label='Demanda')
    ax.set_xticks(hourly_ticks_3)
    ax.set_title('Diagrama de Carga de ' + subtitle + ' 2019' + '\n-Promedio mensual-')
    ax.set_xlabel('Hora del día')
    ax.set_ylabel('Demanda [MW]')
    ax.axvline("17:00", color="C1", linestyle="--", lw=1, alpha=0.8)
    ax.axvline("23:00", color="C1", linestyle="--", lw=1, alpha=0.8)
    ax.text("20:00", 0.15, 'Horas Punta', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), bbox=dict(fc='none', ec='C1', boxstyle='round'), ha='center')
    ax.grid(True, lw=0.8, alpha=0.5)
    ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, one advice to get better and faster answer, you should give a complete working example (including data generation) and tag your question with Python and matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
ax.set_xlim("00:00", "23:00")
```

I wasn't sure whether to delete this post or leave it posted here. It could help other people with the same "problem".